# Regex match after :

Tags: php, regex

I want to select with regex the name and surname in the following sentence (spaces should be ignored)

```
Demandé par Dr :     NAME SURNAME
```

Could you please help me to find the correct regex?

Edit: My attempt was : `(?<=Dr.:....)(.*)` but it's not good as the spaces may changes.

Edit 2: with some changes the best way for me was : (?:Demandé par Dr :|(?!^)\G)\s*\K(.*)

or better `(?:Demand. par Dr :|(?!^)\G)\s*\K(.*)` to avoid the special characters problem ;)

Comment: Though regular expressions exist in many languages, each implementation differs. You should specify which language you need this for.

Comment: Hello Ingo
For php on Linux please ;)
Best regards
Amorino

Comment: You should post your attempt.

Comment: Hello Jerry my attempt was : (?<=Dr.:....)(.*) but it's not good as the spaces may changes. Regards

Comment: @amorino - when adding details like this, it is better to edit the question to include the new info, rather than putting it in a comment.

Comment: Ok Spudley sorry I'm new here 
I'll do it right now ;)

Comment: No worries; we're all new once  :)  By the way, I don't think regex is really needed here at all; a simple `explode()` should be sufficient to get the name (plus a trim to remove the unwanted spaces). See my answer.

Comment: are sure PHP is the right tools to extract data from your file? Did you consider `Perl` or `awk`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regex you can use is:

```
/:\s*(\S+)\s+(\S+)/
```

This will match the `:` and everything after it, ignoring spaces. This assumes that there are no spaces within the names or surnames.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/oG6oS1)

The name will be in `.group(1)` and the surname in `.group(2)`

If you don't want to access groups...

```
preg_match_all('/(?:Demandé par Dr :|(?!^)\G)\s*\K(?:\S+)/', $string)
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/nH6yQ9)

Comment: I just need NAME SURNAME without : and the spaces after it
Could that be possible do you think?

Comment: @amorino You can access the name and surname in the captured groups.

Comment: @amorino If you don't want to access the groups, then use this I guess: [link](http://regex101.com/r/nH6yQ9)

Comment: It would be much better without groups but it doesn't work here : http://regexr.com?368jk

Comment: @amorino I'm not sure why there are so many spaces in your sample... but it can be adjusted with this: http://regexr.com/?368jn

Comment: Hello Jerry I made some changes and all is OK now for me : (?:Demandé par Dr :|(?!^)\G)\s*\K(.*)
Thank you very much

Comment: @amorino `\S+` will match any character except newline, space and tab. This means it will match all special characters. `.*` will match spaces as well and you get NAME and SURNAME in a single match. Didn't you want to exclude all spaces?

Answer (score 2):

This should do it

```
/Demandé par Dr :\s*(\w+)\s+(\w+)/
```

Comment: Hello Ingo thank you
It selected all the sentence but I need to select only NAME SURNAME
Please see here : http://regexr.com?368je
Regards

Comment: @Jerry Correct. @amorino Replace `\w` with the character class(es) you need to match names (that really is up to you). As for only getting the names: Use the captured groups.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this regular expression `[a-zA-Z]+\s[a-zA-Z]+`

If you are looking to find a first and second name only. but if you want to add more, you just have to add `\s[a-zA-Z]+`, It means a space follow by a letter from a to z It could be uppercase or not and the plus sign means it can have more than one letter. I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the name after the colon, you don't really even need a regex. Just split the string on the colon, take the second result, and trim it.

You mentioned you're using PHP, so...

```
$splitData = explode(':',$inputString);
$fullName = trim($splitData[1]);
```

Job done. No regex required.